# Using queries as data for loop in Laravel (or PHP in general)

Tags: php, laravel

it's my first time asking a question here, please bear with me as i'm just started coding not too long ago.
A while ago, my colleague saw my code

```
$roles = new Roles();
foreach($roles->get as $role)
{
   ...irrelevant operation here
}
```

He commented that the way i put my query inside the iteration is wrong, i should change it to

```
$roles = $roles->get();
foreach($roles as $role)
```

He told me that if i put the query as an array expression in foreach loop, it would reference the database each loop, ultimately slowdown the whole site. I'd like to know whether it's true or not, and the logic behind it.

Comment: What does the object Roles() do?

Comment: It's an eloquent model that represents a table, allowing interaction with database. Basically $roles->get() returns all record from a table that Roles represents, table User__roles in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `foreach` loops PHP takes the iterable variable once and uses an internal iterator to process on it. Your colleague's objection applies to simple `for` loops where the continuation condition is executed each time before every iteration.

You can easily construct a test case:

```
<?php
class testClass
{
  private
    $_iteratable = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  public function get()
  {
    echo "get called<br>\n";
    return $this->_iteratable;
  }
}

echo "foreach<br>\n";
$obj = new testClass();
foreach($obj->get() as $key => $value)
{
  echo "$key: $value<br>\n";
}

/* OUTPUT:
foreach
get called
0: a
1: b
2: c
*/

echo "<p>for<br>\n";
$obj = new testClass();
for($i = 0; $i < count($obj->get()); $i++)
{
  echo "$i: {$obj->get()[$i]}<br>\n";
}

/* OUTPUT:
for
get called
get called
0: a
get called
get called
1: b
get called
get called
2: c
get called
?>
```

To enhance performance you might use `foreach($iteratable as &$reference)` since only a reference to the data instead of a probably bigger data value is copied each iteration. Doing so, you will be processing on the original data passed to the foreach loop wich means: You can even manipulate that data. If you use foreach by value you will work on a copy and you can modify your work value without affacting the original data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i'll keep that in mind when i start working on bigger project that requires such data reference.

Answer (score 2):

The $roles->get(); opens the db connection, makes the query, closes the connection.

Every connection to DB (often) is a TCP connection to another host, if you put inside a loop it is called (n) times.
You are slowing the loop by making each iteration wait for DB connection.
If you get all data at once (like with $roles->all()) it puts the data into the RAM and doesn't need to call the DB foreach item.

Hope it helped

Comment: I have never use all() before but get() return an array of object from database, then i loop through that. if i use no constrain then get() should return the same things as all(), in that case, does it still need to connect to database multiple times?

Comment: As Quasimodo stated, I was thinking to the simple "for" loop.
I also was sure the "get" was inside the loop body :(
Thanks to @quasimodo for the clarification and the test case :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant difference between

```
$roles = $roles->get();
foreach($roles as $role)
```

and

```
foreach($roles->get() as $role)
```

in both cases `$roles->get()` will be called just once. Which means that database connection will be executed just once.